# How should query with timezone for timestamp

Tags: mysql, timezone

We saved the timestamp with **UTC**. However, we would like to choose user to their own time zone. There is no problem at display. But problem at the date range query.

> **Asia/Singapore** : 13/03/2017 0:00 AM (0:00)
>
> **UTC** : 12/03/2017 4:00 (16:00) PM

Singapore Timezone user try to query their data betwen 13/03/2017 to 15/03/2017 , some data has been lost because of timezone.

Current query is like

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE created_at between "2018-01-24" and "2018-01-25";
```

Comment: While I think I understand the basic problem you are facing, I still find it hard to determine what your actual question is. Could [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/200081/edit) your question and add some details? Example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `CONVERT_TZ` and it's working fine now.

```
SELECT * FROM re_registers WHERE CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','+08:00') between "2018-01-24" and "2018-01-25";
```

Comment: it is good, but you need to consider the Daylight saving, i.e. if your timezone change daylight saying you have to pass correct +time in it.

Answer (score 0):

The TZ is *not* stored in either datatype.

If you want a picture of the clock on the wall, use `DATETIME`.  Everyone will see the same hour.  That is, the bits on the disk represent *localtime*

If you want to store an instant in time, use `TIMESTAMP`.  Different users in different parts of the world will see different hours.  That is, the bits on disk represent UTC after converting from localtime according to the tz in effect when *writing*.

Store in `2017-03-13`, not `13/03/2017`,  For the latter, use `DATE_FORMAT` when reading.

Retroactively changing a column of `TIMESTAMPs` to `DATETIMEs` (or vice versa) is impossible without knowing what the tz in effect when the value was stored.